# Deleting redundant information with regex

Tags: regex, deduplication

I would like to use regular expressions (.NET) for the following task.

A text file contains the following lines:

```
=650  \1$aPets$xFiction.  
=650  \1$aApartment houses$xFiction.  
=650  \0$aPets$xFiction.  
=650  \0$aApartment houses$xFiction.
```

The regex should identify the cases where lines are identical except for the 8th character (0 vs. 1), & then delete the lines where the 8th character is a 1.

Output would then be:

```
=650  \0$aPets$xFiction.  
=650  \0$aApartment houses$xFiction.
```

(with the rest of the text file unchanged)

If other tools or techniques would be preferable, I'd be happy to learn about those.

Thank you.

Comment: Now  you should try getting a regex for it. Then try writing the .NET code to do it. Without trying anything, don't ask a question here. Come back when you have some doubt in the regex you have come up with or when the .NET code doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Apologies. My regex is still extremely basic -- just recently started learning/ using it -- & this particular problem is way beyond my skill level. Will give it a crack, however, & see how far I get.

Comment: The regular expression pattern `^.......1` will match the string that has `1` as the 8th character. `SomeString[7]` will give you the 8th character which you can check for being `=='1'`. Can you build something around this?

Comment: Thank you; it's a start. Pretty sure I'll be using submatch variables (backreferences) & then the replace function ... Will take me a while to get up to speed :-)